# How can I fix 'color' module import error?

Tags: python, module, colors, stddraw

I have a problem with stddraw python file, when I want to import it
I face module not found error >> no module named 'color'
I tried to install color from pip but it didn't work again!!!

Comment: Have you tried with `pip install colour` instead of 'color'? And, then `import colour`.

Comment: yes I have installed 'colour' and 'color' module, but when I run stddraw file in vs I face an error no module named color

Answer (score 0):

install 'color' module >> https://pypi.org/project/color/
Then install it manually. Go to the directory and enter 'python setup.py install'